# TeamCity build chain - Azure

Tags: azure, svn, teamcity

I have ASP.NET MVC Project which I want to configure on TeamCity.

Builds:
1. Main - Rebuild project
1.1. Download packages
1.2. Rebuild
2. Code Analysis - Do not build but use build result of "Main"
3. Publish to Azure - Do not build but use build result of "Main"

Now I have all in one build configuration. Download packages, rebuild, code analysis and publish. I want to split it.

What dependencies I should set between them? Snapshot or arti? All from SVN.